# NestJs Timeout issue with HttpService

Tags: https, timeout, nestjs

I am facing a **timeout** issue with nestJs Httpservice.

The error number is -60 and error code is 'ETIMEDOUT'.

I am basically trying to call one api after the previous one is successfully.

Here is the first api

```
getUaaToken(): Observable<any> {
    //uaaUrlForClient is defined
    return this.httpService
      .post(
        uaaUrlForClient,
        { withCredentials: true },
        {
          auth: {
            username: this.configService.get('AUTH_USERNAME'),
            password: this.configService.get('AUTH_PASSWORD'),
          },
        },
      )
      .pipe(
        map((axiosResponse: AxiosResponse) => {
          console.log(axiosResponse);

          return this.getJwtToken(axiosResponse.data.access_token).subscribe();
        }),
        catchError((err) => {
          throw new UnauthorizedException('failed to login to uaa');
        }),
      );
  }
```

Here is the second api

```
  getJwtToken(uaaToken: string): Observable<any> {
    console.log('inside jwt method', uaaToken);
    const jwtSignInUrl = `${awsBaseUrl}/api/v1/auth`;
    return this.httpService
      .post(
        jwtSignInUrl,
        { token: uaaToken },
        {
          headers: {
            'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*',
            'Content-type': 'Application/json',
          },
        },
      )
      .pipe(
        map((axiosResponse: AxiosResponse) => {
          console.log('SUCUSUCSCUSS', axiosResponse);
          return axiosResponse.data;
        }),
        catchError((err) => {
          console.log('ERRRORRRORROR', err);

          // return err;
          throw new UnauthorizedException('failed to login for');
        }),
      );
  }
```

Both files are in the same service file. Strangely, when i call the second api through the controller like below. It works fine

```
@Post('/signin')
  @Grafana('Get JWT', '[POST] /v1/api/auth')
  signin(@Body() tokenBody: { token: string }) {
    return this.authService.getJwtToken(tokenBody.token);
  }
```

When the two api's are called, however, the first one works, the second one that is chained is giving me the timeout issue.

Any ideas?

Comment: Try changing `map` in the first API call (the one that calls `this.getJwtToken` to `mergeMap` or `switchMap` so that you don't end up with an Observable of Observable

Comment: Thanks mate @JayMcDoniel. Two things that made it work: changed the http proxy settings and used switchMap. You're a lifesaver.

Answer (score 0):

Two things that made it work: changed the http proxy settings and used switchMap.